# Difference between 'is' and '==' in C#

Tags: c#, comparison

Im trying to understand exactly when is should be used or not used in C#. I have seen answers written for python but nothing on C#. Also it looks like 'is' is doing more than just comparing value, its also checking to see if an object can be cast as another object. Would this lead to a scenario where one could be true and the other false?

Comment: Take an example use of `==` and try re-writing it to use `is`, and take an example useage of `is` and try rewriting it to use `==`, and you'll see how they're different.

Comment: They do completely different things.  There are very few scenarios where `a == b` and `a is b` will both compile.

Comment: The `is` operator returns true if a variable is of a given type. The `==` compares two instances,  if they are the same reference(reference types) or have the same values (value types).

Comment: microsoft (or a simple search) helps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: Did the documentation not answer this? [docs for is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) and the [docs for ==](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)

Comment: if you google c# is, the first result gives you the answer.  FFS, Why do people ask questions without even bothering to search even once first???  (Takes a lot less energy and time.)

Comment: @CameronBelt He's being blunt, but he's not a dick. If you spent the same time googling as you did writing up this post, I almost guarantee that you wouldn't ended up better off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They check completely different things. `is` compares types. `==` compares values.

```
var isString = "Abc" is String; // => true
var equalToString = "Abc" == String; // Error: `string' is a `type' but a `variable' was expected
```

There is one domain where these can both apply, and have different meanings, and that's in type checking:

```
class Car {}
class SportsCar: Car {}

var car = new Car();
var sportsCar = new SportsCar();

/* 1 */ Console.WriteLine(car is Car); // => true, car is exactly of type Car
/* 2 */ Console.WriteLine(sportsCar is Car); // => true, since SportsCar *is a subclass* of Car
/* 3 */ Console.WriteLine(car is SportsCar); // => false, since Car is not a subclass of SportsCar
/* 4 */ Console.WriteLine(sportsCar is SportsCar); // => true, sportsCar is exactly of type SportsCar

/* 5 */ Console.WriteLine(car.GetType() == typeof(Car)); // => true, car is exactly of type Car
/* 6 */ Console.WriteLine(sportsCar.GetType() == typeof(Car)); // => false, since SportsCar *is not exactly* Car
/* 7 */ Console.WriteLine(car.GetType() == typeof(SportsCar)); // => false, since Car is not a subclass of SportsCar
/* 8 */ Console.WriteLine(sportsCar.GetType() == typeof(SportsCar)); // => true, sportsCar is exactly of type SportsCar
```

Lines 1/5, 3/7, and 4/8 both result the same (respectively) but notice that line 2 and 6 differ

Comment: `"Abc" == String` is not `false`.

Comment: `"Abc" == String` will not compile.

Comment: @Servy Fixed. I thought `String` could be treated as a value, seems it can't.

Comment: @SLaks Fixed. I thought `String` could be treated as a value, seems it can't.

Comment: @Rob Why would I not use `var`?

Comment: @Rob, what has reputation to do with C# knowledge? Alexander is swift expert, he doesn't have to know everything. Attempt to give answer is nothing more than attempt, we all make a mistake (I am not saying he did).

Comment: if you know it can only be a bool don't lazy code it, (it's not vb)

Comment: @Rob Do you perhaps think that `var` is actually the same as `object`?  *Every* time you use `var` you know what the type of the variable is.  It *statically* infers the type.  There is never a time that you *don't* know what the type of the variable will be.  The feature *exists* so that you don't need to explicitly type out the type of variables (and also a bit for anonymous types).  Interestingly enough, VB *didn't* have such a feature until a version *after* `var` was added to C#; they created a feature to *emulate* this feature of C#, so using `var` isn't emulating VB.

Comment: @Rob I am using `var` ***exactly*** because I know it can only be a `bool`. Saying `bool` would add no new information over `var`. It would be worthwhile to explicitly state the type *when it's not clear what the inferred type will be*. That is not the case here.